# Keyboard shortcuts not always triggering on a WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I got some keyboard shortcuts set on a WPF UserPanel this way:

```
<UserControl.../>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=CheckShortcutsCommand}"    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"    />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
...
```

It globally works excep that the CheckShortcutsCommand command is invoked only if the focus is on a control of the UserControl.

So if I click on a textbox, or listbox of the usercontrol and hit a keyboard key, it will trigger the command.
If i click on the usercontrol background, it does not trigger it.

Is this the expected behaviour? How can I have the command to be triggered even if no control is focussed (if I click on the background and hit a key)?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way keyboard focus works. If what you actually want is to have keyboard bindings that work regardless of what control in the window is focused, you're going to need to put them in the Window.

```
<Window.InputBindings>

    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="C" Command="{Binding CheckShortcutsCommand}" />

    <!-- More KeyBindings and MouseBindings here -->

</Window.InputBindings>
```

If `i:Interaction.Triggers` really is what you need to be doing, you'd do that just as you have it -- but in the `Window`, not the `UserControl`.

If you're trying to use your `UserControl` as a means of adding a packaged group of Commands to arbitrary windows, that's a neat idea, and it's doable, but this is the wrong way to do it in WPF.

You could write a static method which takes a reference to a `UserControl`, finds the `UserControl`'s top-level parent via `VisualTreeHelper`, and copies all of the `UserControl`'s input bindings to the top level parent. Then you'd call that method in the `UserControl`'s `Loaded` event. Make that a base class and you could bang out a dozen different "command package" UserControls.

You could also write an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943(v=vs.95).aspx) that adds a set of commands to a Window's `InputBindings`:

```
<Window
    ...etc....
    myProps:AddFooBarCommands="True"
    ...etc....
    >
    ...etc....
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ed! Switching the KeyBinding  code to the window perfectly made the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most robust solution, but if your UserControl's background is "clickable" you could apply focus to one of the controls inside of it so that the keyboard shortcuts work?